# How to get array index of nested object in autoform?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I need to set slugs of my subcategories ,and i am using autovalue for this. I need to know the index of actual field for when i use arrays. There is a wild card for this?

Eg:

subcategories.$.subs.$.name

```
  subcategories: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: true,
  },
  "subcategories.$.name": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  "subcategories.$.slug": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      omit: true
    },
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.field('subcategories.$.name').isSet) {
        return s.slugify( (this.field('subcategories.$.name').value).toLowerCase() );
      }
    },
  },
  "subcategories.$.subs": {
    type: [Object],
    optional: true,
  },
  "subcategories.$.subs.$.name": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  "subcategories.$.subs.$.slug": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      omit: true
    },
    autoValue: function(i) {
      if (this.field('subcategories.$.subs.$.name').isSet) {
        return s.slugify( (this.field('subcategories.$.subs.$.name').value).toLowerCase() );
      }
    },
  },
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected result by changing the schema. Besides getting more organized, this.siblingField('name') works!

Code:

```
Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories');
Schemas = {};

Schemas.Subs = new SimpleSchema({
  "name": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  "slug": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      omit: true,
    },
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.siblingField('name').isSet) {
        return s.slugify( (this.siblingField('name').value).toLowerCase() );
      }
    },
  },
});

Schemas.Subcategories = new SimpleSchema({
  "name": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  "slug": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      omit: true,
    },
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.siblingField('name').isSet) {
        return s.slugify( (this.siblingField('name').value).toLowerCase() );
      }
    },
  },
  "subs": {
    type: [Schemas.Subs],
    optional: true,
  },
});

Schemas.Categories = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  slug:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    index: 1,
    autoform: {
      omit: true
    },
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.field('name').isSet) {
        return s.slugify( (this.field('name').value).toLowerCase() );
      }
    },
  },
  subcategories: {
    type: [Schemas.Subcategories],
    optional: true,
  },
});

Categories.attachSchema(Schemas.Categories);
```